# How to handle protractor test to run in a sequential order

Tags: protractor, synchronous

This is my Block which contain an `element.element(by.model("$ctrl.benchmark.name"));`
This is not present on Dom. It give me error that element is not on page but still execute all lines of code written after it. I want this to handle in sequential way if above passes then go to next only. How can I handle these types of problem in Protractor.

```js
it("Test BenchMark",function(){
    browser.getTitle().then(function (name) {
        console.log(name);

        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.linkText("Manage Benchmarks")).click();
        browser.sleep(4000)


        //element(by.xpath("//main[@class='ng-scope']//a[text()='Create Benchmark']")).click();
        console.log("megha");
        element(by.model("$ctrl.benchmark.name")).sendKeys("bench");
        element(by.buttonText("Save")).click();
        console.log(megha);
        element(by.xpath("//button[@class='dropdown-toggle']")).click();
        console.log("dropdown clicked")

    });
```

Comment: One option would be to switch to typescript and use async/await for each of your tests

Answer (score 0):

The behavior which you are expecting will not be handled by Protractor, it will be by testing framework(ex: Jasmine). But

```
 "Jasmine doesn't support failing early, in a single spec. The idea is to give     
  you all of the failures in case that helps figure out what is really wrong 
  in your spec"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browser.wait()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) combined with [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).

`browser.wait()` blocks control flow execution until a promise is resolved, and Expected Conditions all evaluate to a promise.

So in your case, you could use either [presenceOf()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) and/or [visibilityOf()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf).

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var el = element(by.model("$ctrl.benchmark.name"));
var present = EC.presenceOf(el); // wait for it to be added to DOM
var visible = EC.visibilityOf(el); // wait for it to be visible on page
browser.wait(EC.and(present, visible), 10000); // wait maximum of 10 seconds
// rest of code
```

Comment: `browser.wait()` returns a promise so in order to write code after that you need to use `.then()`. With many waits it gets very nested.

Comment: @FCin You don't need a `.then()`, the promise is fulfilled with the Expected Condition

Comment: But you have to use `.then()` to resolve it in order to proceed with tests. I'm talking about situation where you have `browser.wait(EC.and(present, visible), 10000);` and next line is `console.log('abc');`. Console.log will execute before `browser.wait` finishes unless you use `.then()`

Comment: No, you don't have to explicitly resolve it.  That's because `console.log()` isn't a promise, Protractor maintains a queue of pending promises.  But if you were to give it another command, such as a `.click()` or an `expect` statement, they would execute in the proper order.